How do I convert string representation of duration into decimal format in R?
In my data file, I have a column that represents the total duration that individuals students spend on a website working through different learning modules. For example, a student spent 11 hours and 30 minutes, so their value would be "11h30m". A student who only spent 59 minutes on the website would have "59m".
How do I put this into decimal format so that the student who spent 11 hours and 30 minutes would have a value of 11.5?
I'm very new to R, so I'm really not sure where to start at all. I made a function in Python to fix it, but now sure how I'd tackle this in R.

Changing the minute m to M, then using as.period, finally getting the floating point representation with as.numeric
dat <- c("11h30m", "59m")

library(lubridate)

as.numeric(as.period(sub("m", "M", dat)), units="hours")
[1] 11.5000000  0.9833333

If you want to stay base R try
sapply(strsplit(sub("h",".",dat), "\\."), \(x) 
  sum(as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("m", x), as.numeric(sub("m", "", x)) / 60, x))))
[1] 11.5000000  0.9833333

It splits the duration in 2 parts, getting the minutes into the decimal representation if present.

1) as.POSIXlt Using only base R (no packages) we first define a function, na0, that converts NA's to zero and then use as.POSIXlt to parse the input, x.  To parse the hours we use the fact that as.POSIXlt ignores junk after the format is matched and to parse the minutes we first remove the hours using sub.  We wrap the calculation in a function dur2hrs to make it easier to reuse.
na0 <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
 
dur2hrs <- function(x) {
  na0(as.POSIXlt(x, format = "%Hh")$hour) +
     na0(as.POSIXlt(sub(".*h", "", x), format = "%Mm")$min) / 60
}

# test
x <- c("11h30m", "59m", "3h")

dur2hrs(x)
## [1] 11.50000  0.98333  3.00000

2) strcapture This alternative also uses only base R making use of string manipulation instead of as.POSIXlt.  na0 and test vector x from above are used.  strcapture returns a data frame with the portions matched to the (...) parts of the  regular expression.
dur2hrs_b <- function(x) {
  proto <- list("", h = 0, "", m = 0)
  with(strcapture("((\\d+)h)?((\\d+)m)?", x, proto), na0(h) + na0(m)/60)
}

dur2hrs_b(x)
## [1] 11.50000  0.98333  3.00000

  
  

